# Combining multiple ListPlot with different abscissas

Tags: plotting

I have a complicated function and my computer crashes when I try to plot it using ListPlot from 0 to 30.

So what I want to do is instead of plotting the function from 0 to 30, I cut it into segments, i.e. 0 to 3, 3 to 6, and so on, then I want to combine all these segments.

How do I combine these segments?

Thank you

Comment: Do you understand why it crashes?

Comment: I think my computer crashes because it ran out of memory

Comment: This is how to do what you asked. list1 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x,0,3}]; list2 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x,3,6}]; list3 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x,6,9}]; ListPlot[{list1, list2, list3}] but I question whether that will really solve your problem.

Comment: I tried this and it works. Thanks! How do I make the different segments into the same color and linestyle?

Comment: Study this hint: ListPlot[{list1, list2, list3}, PlotStyle -> Red]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Show` with `PlotRange->All`

```
plots = Table[ListPlot[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, a, a + 2, 0.1}], 
                       PlotStyle -> Hue[a/10]], {a, 0, 6, 2}]
```

[image]

```
Show[plots, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to build lines from values and then use Show@Graphics[{specifications, lines}, options], which I think gives you more control. Table[ ] would also let you use a larger step so you do not run into memory issues. For example 
line1=Line@Table[{z,function[z]}, {z, min, max, step}]
plt1=Show@Graphics[{
Dashing[.02],
Black,
line1
},Axes->True]